# Scrapy pipeline queries not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, scrapy, psycopg2

Hello i'm trying to insert into postgresql using scrapy.

I'm trying to insert data into multiple columns in 1 database with 1 spider

The code for insert into 1 table worked, but when i change my database it required multiple tables to be inserted.

The code for pipeline query i rewrited and now it's returning with "not all arguments converted during string formatting" when i try to run my spider

I know it's something wrong with my query with using "%s" in python but i can't figured how to solve or change the query.

**Here is my pipelines.py:**

```
import psycopg2
class TutorialPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        hostname = 'localhost'
        username = 'postgres'
        password = '123' # your password
        database = 'discount'
        self.connection = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database)
        self.cur = self.connection.cursor()

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.cur.close()
        self.connection.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.cur.execute("insert into discount(product_name,product_price,product_old_price,product_link,product_image) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(item['product_name'],item['product_price'],item['product_old_price'],item['product_link'],item['product_image']))
        self.cur.execute("insert into categories(name) values(%s)",(item['category_name']))
        self.cur.execute("insert into website(site) values(%s)",(item['product_site']))
        self.connection.commit()
        return item
```

**EDIT: HERE THE TRACEBACK ERRORS**

> self.cur.execute("insert into categories(name)
>   values(%s)",(item['category_name'])) TypeError: not all arguments
>   converted during string formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use named arguments. Simplified example:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.cur.execute('''
        insert into discount(product_name, product_price) 
        values(%(product_name)s, %(product_price)s)''',
        item)
    self.cur.execute('''
        insert into categories(name) 
        values(%(category_name)s)''',
        item)
    self.cur.execute('''
        insert into website(site) 
        values(%(product_site)s)''',
        item)
    self.connection.commit()
    return item
```

Read more on [Passing parameters to SQL queries.](http://psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)